# Existence of continuous open mappings between Banach Spaces

Tags: reference-request, normed-spaces, banach-spaces

Can anybody provide some references dealing with the conditions under which there exists a continuous open mapping between two Banach spaces?

For example, does there exist a continuous open mapping between a finite dimensional normed linear space and $C(X)$? $($  $X$ is a compact metric space$)$

Comment: I am aware of the Open Mapping Theorem. But it does not talk about the existence of a continuous open map between two Banach spaces. It says if there exists a linear continuous surjective map between two Banach spaces, then the map is open. I want to know when does a continuous open map between two Banach spaces exists. I have relaxed the linearity and surjectivity of the map.

Comment: Every bounded linear open map $X\to Y$ between two Banach spaces $X$,$Y$ must be surjective. Thus having an open map $X\to Y$ is synonymous having a surjective $X\to Y$.

Comment: The map need not be linear.

Comment: apologies for the oversight. A continuous open map is a homemorphism. Every pair of separable Banach spaces are homeomorphic https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anderson%E2%80%93Kadec_theorem . If the image of a continuous open map $T:X\to Y$ is a linear subspace of $Y$, then the map must be surjective. I do not know the answer if you do not require $imT$ to be a linear space.

Comment: “A continuous open map is a homeomorphism”- I do not think this is true. Consider the projection mapping from the Euclidean plane to the real line.

Comment: why do I assume the map in question is injective? I must have said "an injective continuous open map is a homeomorphism onto its image". Your example is absolutely valid.